# Display Azure Subfolders in Node.js project

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I am trying to make an filesharing applikation with Node and Express, using Azure as data-storage.

I am struggling with displaying subfolders of my containers.

My code looks like this:

1. I create the subfolders like this, with the intention of hiding the '$$$.$$$'-file:

   ```
   app.post('/folderhandler', function (req, res) {
   var containerName = req.query.id;
   var folderName = req.body.folderName;

   var folder = folderName + '/$$$.$$$';

   blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromText(
       containerName,
       folder,
       'Hello, World!',
       function (error, result, response) {
           if (error) {
               console.log("Couldn't upload string");
               console.error(error);
           } else {
               console.log('String uploaded successfully');
           }
       });
   res.redirect('/container/' + containerName);
   });
   ```
2. And then i tried to use the new 'Subfolder', as the 'container' variable in my displayBlobs function. But this doesn't work:

   ```
       app.get('/container/:containername/:subcontainer', function (req, res) {

       var containerName = req.params.containername;
       var subContainer = req.params.subcontainer;

       blobSvc.listContainersSegmented(null, function (err, containers) {

           blobSvc.listBlobsSegmented(subContainer, null, function (error, blobs) {

               res.render('manager.ejs', {
                   error: error,
                   title: 'Manager ' + containerName,
                   pageID: 'containers',
                   containername: subContainer,
                   listContainers: containers.entries,
                   listBlobs: blobs.entries,
                   breadcrumbs: [{
                       href: '/manager',
                       text: 'Manager'
                   }, {
                       href: '/container/' + containerName,
                       text: containerName
                   }, {
                       text: subContainer,
                       active: true
                   }]
               });
           });
       });
   });
   ```

I think i have tried everything, so im open to suggestions :)

- thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the values for `containerName` and `subContainer`? Also please tell us what you're seeing (actual behavior) and what you're expecting to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you made a mistake in function [`listBlobsSegmented(container, currentToken [, options], callback)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#listBlobsSegmented__anchor), the first parameter should be a container name, not subfolder name.

If you want to display blob items in the subfolder, please use function [`listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix(container, prefix, currentToken [, options], callback)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix__anchor) instead, then you can pass the subfolder name as the second parameter `prefix`.